# How to access private functions of another package in Golang?

Tags: function, go

I want to access a private function of a package called "pastry". But it generates error as:
invalid reference to unexported identifier

Specify the way by which private functions of golang are accessible in main.

Comment: You can't. That's the way the language works.

Comment: The whole idea of "private" is to be non-accessible.

Comment: Actually it is possible, see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also add public proxy-function.

For example:

You have package-private function

```
func foo() int {
    return 42
}
```

You can create public function in the same package, which will call the package-private function and return it's result

```
func Bar() int {
    return foo()
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use `go:linkname` to map functions from same/different package
to some function in yours. For example like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    _ "net"
    _ "unsafe"
)

//go:linkname lookupStaticHost net.lookupStaticHost
func lookupStaticHost(host string) []string

func main() {
    fmt.Println(lookupStaticHost("localhost"))
}
```

will produce `[127.0.0.1 ::1]` when executed on my machine.

Comment: what about a struct function?

Comment: Warning: unexported variables like `int` or `bool` are often *inlined*. `go:linkname` will be of no help in changing those at run time.

Answer (score 8):

Private functions are, by definition, not accessible outside the package in which they are declared.

If you need that function outside that package, you must make it public (change the function name, turning the first letter in upper case).

Eg: if you have `func doSomething()` rename it to `func DoSomething()` and use it outside the package with `<package name>.DoDomething()`

Answer (score 3):

in the package (let's say mypackage) where you have pastry function add:

```
var Pastry = pastry
```

in main package:

```
mypackage.Pastry()
```

Comment: You are assuming, that he approves altering the source of the package.